# Using a fn try_parse<T>(value: T) to consolidate different TryFrom<T> implementations for different T

Tags: rust, traits

Suppose I have a struct call `SevenDigits`, as its name suggests, it is a type that consists of 7 and only 7 digits.

```
struct SevenDigits([u8; 7]);
```

I have implemented the `std::convert::TryFrom` trait for three types: `&str`, `Vector`, and `u32`. For example, for the implementation of `u32` it is:

```
impl TryFrom<u32> for ICDigits {
    type Error = &'static str;

    fn try_from(value: u32) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        let mut digits = [0; 7];
        let mut remaining = value;

        for i in (0..7).rev() {
            let digit = remaining % 10;
            remaining /= 10;

            digits[i] = digit as u8;
        }

        if remaining > 0 {
            Err("Number is too large to fit in an array of 7 digits")
        } else {
            Ok(ICDigits(digits))
        }
    }
}
```

Suppose now I want to implement a method `pub fn try_parse<T: TryInto<SevenDigits>>(value: T) -> Result<Self, &'static str> {` where `T` is any generic type that implements the `TryInto<SevenDigits>` trait.

My natural implementation for this function is:

```
  pub fn try_parse<T: TryInto<SevenDigits>>(value: T) -> Result<Self, &'static str> {
    TryFrom::try_from(value)
  }
}
```

Upon `cargo check`, this gives me two errors:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<SevenDigitsas TryFrom<T>>::Error == &str`
  --> src/digits.rs:25:5
   |
25 |     TryFrom::try_from(value)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `Infallible`, found `&str`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `SevenDigits: From<T>` is not satisfied
  --> src/digits.rs:25:5
   |
25 |     TryFrom::try_from(value)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<T>` is not implemented for `SevenDigits`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<SevenDigits>` for `T`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `TryFrom<T>` for `ICDigits`
help: consider introducing a `where` clause, but there might be an alternative better way to express this requirement
   |
9  | impl SevenDigits where SevenDigits: From<T> {
   |               +++++++++++++++++++++++
```

The error messages are hopelessly confusing.
How can I implement this `pub fn try_parse` function?

Answer (score 2):

I fiddled with your example till I made it work:

```rust
pub struct SevenDigits([u8; 7]);

pub fn try_parse<T>(value: T) -> Result<SevenDigits, &'static str> 
where
    T: TryInto<SevenDigits, Error = &'static str>,
{
    value.try_into()
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c14c0bbecb4dee9c2e547937d6b7881c)

You can't use `TryFrom::try_from` with only the trait bounds `T: TryInto<U>` here, because of [this default implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html#impl-TryFrom%3CU%3E-for-T): `impl<T, U> TryFrom<U> for T where U: Into<T>`. You must use `TryInto::try_into` directly instead. Implementing `TryFrom<T> for U` gives you an automatic implementation of `TryInto<U> for T`, looking approximately like this:

```rust
impl<T, U> const TryInto<U> for T
where
    U: TryFrom<T>,
{
    type Error = U::Error;

    fn try_into(self) -> Result<U, U::Error> {
        U::try_from(self)
    }
}
```

That does not mean that you can use `TryFrom<T>` when `T` implements `TryInto<U>`, because this relationship is not reflexive, i.e. it goes only in one direction from `TryFrom` to `TryInto`.

Other than that you only had a type mismatch with the associated `Error` type. You must explicitly tell the compiler that the `TryInto<SevenDigits>` implementation of `T` returns a `&'static str` as error to make it match the return type of your function.

Comment: You can very well [use `TryFrom`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5794003e2e72bfa8eefb2a169ff20c0f) but as you stated the `TryInto` bound is more flexible.

Comment: Oh yes of course. Changing the trait bounds from `T: TryInto<U>` to `U: TryFrom<T>` will work, too. I clarified my answer. Thanks for pointing out @cafce25

Answer (score 0):

So it seems there are actually 2 errors.

Firstly, the `TryFrom` trait which implies `TryInto` needs you to define an associated error type. Here, you've set the error type for `u32` (and I assume the rest of them) to be `&'static str`. However, the generic doesn't know this so the actual error type is `T ::Error`, since it can be anything. To fix this you can either change the function return type or use `match` and return a string error yourself.

Then, the way you are using the `TryInto` with `TryForm` doesn't work (and honestly I'm not quite sure why). To fix it you can use `try_into()` or use a `where` clause to define the trait bound `SevenDigits: TryFrom<T>`.

Here are two example solutions that work:

1. Changing the function signature and using `TryInto`

```rust
pub fn try_parse<T: TryInto<SevenDigits>>(value: T) -> Result<Self, T::Error> {
    value.try_into()
}
```

2. Using trait bound and `TryFrom`

```rust
pub fn try_parse<T>(value: T) -> Result<Self, &'static str> where SevenDigits: TryFrom<T> {
    match TryFrom::try_from(value) {
        Ok(seven_digits) => Ok(seven_digits),
        Err(_) => Err("Number is too large to fit in an array of 7 digits")
    }
}
```